# Is it Pajamas? Or Shampoo? Maybe a Cheetah? Oh I know, it's:

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, grid-deduction

[image: pse.png]

> [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HU0n7wrOtjkyAclCPGQEzXeyuIa-AR1NS6X33inone4/edit?usp=sharing) version.

Title hint:

> Google is your friend.

Comment: Welcome to PSE - this is an impressive looking first puzzle, so nice job :)

Comment: @Rubio should I supply an excel version too or they don't do things like that here?

Comment: We don't want people to download files of unknown provenance to their own computers, as that's a Really Bad Idea™ - but putting something like this up as a Google Docs spreadsheet might not be a bad idea, as it's large enough that recreating it from the image is ... well ... unpleasant

Comment: @WesleySitu right a typo :( I'll correct it and review for more.

Comment: Also, it appears to be impossible to know some of them - there's a large gap a bit right of the bottom center, and I count 3 squares there that don't have an adjacent clue.

Comment: @Deusovi agreed. Also I believe there is another typo another just left and down from the center. Its a 3 to the left of a 5 with an 8 to the upper right of the 5. Great puzzle though, enjoyed thouroughly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's ...

> An Avatar

This is how to find the answer

> After investigating the grid I had noticed that 9 squares surround each number which is coincidently the highest number in the grid. The 9s and 0s seemed kind of clustered and the numbers taper down from the 9s, so I thought it may represent an image if the boxes were filled in accordingly. I began to fill in each box surrounding and including the 9s. Then continued on to the 8s and left one box empty around it that may have been near a lower number. A 7 for example. Then continued down from there until the image started to appear. A 0 will have no coloured in boxes connected to the sides or coners of that 0 box. A 1 will have one coloured in box connected to the sides or corners of that box, and so on until 9 where you fill in it, and all the boxes surrounding it. The resulting image is the same as the OPs avatar.

This is my results.

> [image: mordechai avatar]

Now how does this lead to the answer for the title question.

> The title refers to shampoo, pajamas and a cheetah which apparenlty are all of hindi origins, which avatar is aswell. Great puzzle.

Comment: Great job. Still few missing like the 2 6's at the right hair part. What's left unsolved is the title.

Comment: You're going to want to explain why the filled-in cells are filled in.  *("Yes, typically we require some sort of explanation for why you think this is the answer. (Otherwise, I'd've posted this a while ago!) – Deusovi♦ 1 hour ago")*

Comment: Oops, my mistake. I'll fix it up now, thank you for your patience.

Comment: I did write a computer program to pixelate the image, but numbered them by hand so typos are inevitable.

Comment: Well, the items in the title have something trivial in common. This should head you to the right direction.

Comment: The profile image source is actually given on OP's profile page.  As for the title, these words all originate from Hindi, though it's not clear to me how that relates to the puzzle.

Comment: @Rubio You have a lead.

Comment: @Rubio Thanks did not see that. Tried to find source but had difficulties on mobile.

Comment: AFAIK bachacha isn't English. You can surely find a full list of English words from Hindi somewhere on the Internet.

Comment: @ Rubio Updated answer once again. Also, should have read your comment earlier aswell it would have made it easier to connect. Found a reference on google to a book that helped pin point the relation in the title words

Comment: @Mordechai Another hit and a miss, my mistake. Under estimated the difficulty of this and appreciate the hints.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_words_of_Hindi_or_Urdu_origin) has a complete list. Don't think of the image itself but rather of its context.

Comment: Somewhere close to the top of the list.

Comment: @Mordechai was just on that site too but was stuck thinking inside the box and kept passing the answer while it was starring me in the face.

Comment: Kudos you got it. Now do yourself a favor and edit your post to make it neat. Start off with a seperate spoiler explaining the title like "It's... >! ...Your Avatar. " with some explaination. Then a new spoiler with the grid results.

Comment: @Mordechai will do. I will clean it up abit and add a title with the answer. Im still new to answering on SE puzzling and having a bit of trouble with adding spoliers but i'll get it up asap. Thanks again for the awesome puzzle.